# Hi, I need to know how to insert a large amount of text into SQLite because I create an application for a book with Ionic

Tags: sqlite

"i am developing a mobile application with Ionic for a book that has a lot of content, grouping in
 several parts, subpart, title and chapter. I chose to use SQLite, and I'm looking for a way to 
 load all its contents into my SQLite database and if anyone has an idea or suggestion to help me 
 do things well I'll be delighted."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load contents in text files to sqlite table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317929/load-contents-in-text-files-to-sqlite-table)

Answer (score 1):

The following illustrates how to use the python `sqlite3` module to import a (UTF-8) text file:

```
import sqlite3

def create_table():
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytext( mytext TEXT );""")

def insert_file(filename):
    sql = "INSERT INTO mytext(mytext) VALUES(?)"

    cursor.execute(sql, (open(filename, "r").read(),))
    conn.commit()

db_file_name = 'text-file.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file_name)
cursor = conn.cursor()
create_table()

insert_file("text.txt")

conn.close()
```

(Tested with python3.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to import a text file, e.g. as a BLOB, on a line-to-row basis, using sqlite's "archive" mode, and so on.

If you want the entire file as a single TEXT cell in a table, then (subject to the limitation described below) you can use `.import` by carefully selecting values for the separators.

Multibyte separators are not supported when importing, but control characters such as Control-A and Control-B can be used.

So you could proceed like so:

```
CREATE TABLE text("text" text)';
.separator ^A ^B 
.import text.txt text
```

where `^A` should be replaced by a literal control-A, and similarly for `^B`.

#### Limitation

> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000).

Comment: Your example would be more clear if you renamed your table, column, and file. The word "text" shows up in too many places to make it clear.